# Routing Business Branches: Granular access control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, roles, access-control

How should ASP.NET MVC routes be structured to allow granular role-based access control to **business branches**?

Every business entity is related to a branch, either by itself or via its parent entities. Is there an elegant way to authorize actions based on user-roles for any number of branches?

### 1. {branch} in route?

```
{branch}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

**Action:**

```
[Authorize(Roles="Technician")]
public ActionResult BusinessWidgetAction(BusinessObject obj)
{
    // Authorize will test if User has Technician role in branch context
    // ...
}
```

### 2. Retrieve branch from business entity?

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult BusinessWidgetAction(BusinessObject obj)
{
    if (!User.HasAccessTo("WidgetAction", obj.Branch))
        throw new HttpException(403, "No soup for you!"); // or redirect

    // ...
}
```

### 3. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Looking at your other question as well - my feeling is that you need to re-consider the way your Access/Security works. I understand the need the need for granular control and it would seem that there are many restrictions that you need - this for me is the indication for a re-think.

Comment: @Ahmad: Should I be looking at ACL?

Comment: Not too sure about ACL.. however I using a `custom membership provider` will help.  You want to `authorize actions based on user-roles` simple enough for the default membership provider however the additional restriction is `for any number of branches` - so is this actually a Role->Branches (eg User is in Admin role for some branches) relation or a User->Branches (cant think of example) relation. I could possibly be missing something!!

Comment: I have a tables for `Branches` (eg. Cape Town), `Roles` (eg. Admin, Techie) and `Users` (John, Jill, Peter). with a `UserRoles` table that keeps track of the **user**, **branch** and **role**, eg. (Peter, Cape Town, Techie). I like Runeborg's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335315/access-control-in-asp-net-mvc-depending-on-input-parameters-service-layer/1336404#1336404

Comment: I am already using a custom membership and role provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the same codebase on separate applications and databases for each business branch. This means I have to update each individually, but allows forking of features.

I rolled my own `[BranchAuthorize(Roles = "Editor, Stock Keeper")]` attribute which checks the authenticated user's roles against the controller action's required roles and displays a message detailing the required roles if none are assigned.

Unified branch access control would require a separate authorization service, but would allow for central rights administration.