# Asp.Net MVC Model Validation with permissions on data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, validation, model

I have a dropdownlist on UI with data populated from database. I have 2 roles user and admin. 
Do we have option to display error based on model attribute if user have no permission to access data like the below.

```
[permission]
public details {get; set; }
```

I am trying to show validation message to user like "you dont have permission to access dropdown". Can you throw me some idea if I can use [authorize] and display error message?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know how permissions are controlled in your application. You may find an inspiration for implementing that here:

   http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx

   and here:

   [Access Control in ASP.NET MVC using  [Flags] based Enum to int permissions management in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987039/access-control-in-asp-net-mvc-using-flags-based-enum-to-int-permissions-manag)
2. The most primitive way of restricting an access to a user-control depending on (role) permissions is hiding it from unwelcomed users:

   ```
   @if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
       @Html.DropdownListFor(
           expression: m => m.SelectedItemId, 
           selectList: Model.YourCollection, 
           optionLabel: "some text"
       )
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a AuthorizeAttribute like this.

```
public class FVAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly bool _authorize;
    private readonly string[] _roles;

    public FVAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        _authorize = true;
    }



}
```

and then use something like

[FVAuthorize(Roles = "Administrator, NameOfMethodHereThatCreatesDropdown")]

public details {get; set; }