# Where should access control logic live in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET using MVC and code-first entity framework (with razor). I have been finding a lot of conflicting information on the topic and I thought I would turn to the SO community to try to clear some things up.

From Model to Controller to View, where should the access logic live? For example (simplified for this post):

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private Repo _repo;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        Business business = _repo.FindBusiness(id);
        if (CurrentUser.UserId == business.GeneralManager.UserId ||
            CurrentUser.Father.UserId == business.Owner.UserId)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Business = business;
            return View();
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        Business business = _repo.FindBusiness(employee.business.ID);
        if (CurrentUser.UserId == business.GeneralManager.UserId ||
            CurrentUser.Father.UserId == business.Owner.UserId)
        {
            _repo.Save(employee);
            Return Redirect(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want the current user to be able to create a new business if the current user is the general manager of the business or if his dad owns the place. What I mean to point out here is that it's not dependent on the user's role, but instead some business logic for why they can act.

Similarly, I want to be able to show or hide a link in the view base on the *same condition* eg:

```
...
@if (CurrentUser.UserId == business.GeneralManager.UserId ||
     CurrentUser.Father.UserId == business.Owner.UserId)
     {
        @Html.ActionLink(...)
     }
...
```

I definitely don't want to do it this way. My question is: if the access logic can be bundled as a single method, where does that method "belong" in mvc? Should it be a readonly property of a ViewModel? Should there be some static access controller? Part of the model itself? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best mechanism to implement granular security (i.e. authorization) in an ASP.NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315221/what-is-the-best-mechanism-to-implement-granular-security-i-e-authorization-i)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ActionFilters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) for this, take a look at [this](http://jacopretorius.net/2010/01/permission-based-access-in-asp-net-mvc.html) example.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315221/what-is-the-best-mechanism-to-implement-granular-security-i-e-authorization-i) answer for authorization also.

After writing your ActionFilter logic, your controller will look like this:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private Repo _repo;

    [CustomActionFilter] //your ACL logic will be here.
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
       //no acl logic in here.
    }

    [CustomActionFilter] //your ACL logic will be here.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
       //no acl logic in here.
    }
}
```

The ActionFilters can be applied at the Controller level also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a little confused about how this helps. So for *every* action I have on a controller I would have to implement a custom ActionFilter to hold the access control logic? That seems very excessive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You can have ActionFilters at the Controller level also, you don't need to repeated in every Action.

Comment: What I don't understand is how creating a custom ActionFilter helps remove the guts of the 'if', meaning (CurrentUser.UserId == busines.....) from the controller and also makes it so I can conditionally hide an ActionLink from the view base on the same conditions. If the conditions for CanCreate() are different than CanView() or CanModifySalary() then wouldnt I need to create a custom ActionFilter for each action??

Comment: @AIng yes, you will ActionFilter for each action. However, usually you users fall in few categories: [regular-users, admins, etc]. So you should'nt need to write many CustomActionFIlters, just ONE for each category (regular-users, admins, etc).